# wrtie.csv with sys.date at the end of the file name in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, format, save

How i can save `CSV` file with `sys.Date` at the end of the file name? Below is my `FakeData`.

```
set.seed(123)

FakeData <- data.frame(A = runif(100,1,5), Z = runif(100,10,100))
```

I tried the following code but it didn't save the file correctly.

```
write.csv(FakeData, file = paste("myfile.csv_",Sys.Date()))
```

Comment: write.csv(file = paste("myfile", "_", "Sys.Date()",".csv"))?

Comment: Thanks@maarvd- your code worked with `Sys.Date()` without quotation.

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways of doing this. @maarvd mentioned one, but I prefer the `sprintf` method.

```
> paste("myfile_", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
[1] "myfile_2020-09-11.csv"
> sprintf("myfile_%s.csv", Sys.Date())
[1] "myfile_2020-09-11.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @maarvd said in the comments. The ".csv" file extension should go at the end of the filename .

Check that the filename string is something like: `myfile_20200911.csv` before saving.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `glue`

```
as.character(glue::glue("myfile_s{Sys.Date()}.csv"))
```